# Business card reader or OCR Library for iPhone SDK

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ocr, iphone

I want to develop a Business card reader or OCR Library (Open Source) for iPhone.

I saw reference for www.code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/ but i don't know how to use it. I also download zip file http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-3.00.tar.gz but don't know how to use it into my project.

Can anyone give me suggestion for this or any example will be very useful.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If a commercial solution would be feasible here as well, you might consider our business card scanner API. Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops this https://www.snapaddy.com/en/blog/post/business-card-scanning-api-alternative-for-abbyy-cloud-ocr-sdk.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS:

He's never instantiating the 'tess' variable. Simply add `[self startTesseract];` to the `viewDidLoad()` method in OCRDemoViewController and it will work like a charm.

Comment: What OCRDemoViewController? I don't see any

Comment: I wrote ~3 years ago, so my comment may not apply anymore. Anyway, here is the fix I was talking about (I've sent a pull request to the original author): https://github.com/nolanbrown/Tesseract-iPhone-Demo/commit/6338e61e413ca179dc0d0d7807e6510bad98a631